# Automate opening of DOS program under DOSBox / Windows 7

Tags: dosbox

I use [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/) and it works pretty well, but each time I want to run the application I have to launch DOSBox, then type:

```
mount c c:\path\to\app
c:
cd app
app.exe
```

Can I somehow automate the process, like with a batch file or something?

Or are there other DOS emulators that let you launch programs easier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DOSBox has [this feature itself](http://www.dosbox.com/wiki/Basic_Setup_and_Installation_of_DosBox#Quick_start), defined on the configuration file:

> You can save yourself some time by having DOSBox automatically MOUNT your folders and change the drive to C:. In original DOS based operating systems a file called AUTOEXEC.BAT contained any commands that the user wanted executed every time the computer booted up. This functionality is simulated by the [autoexec] section of the dosbox.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in VB using:

```
dos32Proc = Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\Program Files (x86)\DOSBox-0.74\DOSBox.exe", " -c mrpd"); 
dos32Proc.WaitforExit()
```

`mrpd` is a bat file, and will execute several lines in the DOSBOX command prompt and finish with the `exit` command. You will also need a `mount` command to ensure you are in the correct directory for the command prompt.